# Why ScheduledExecutorService stop when I open other application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm using simple ScheduledExecutorService implementation and everything is working fine.But when I open other application like google chrome or game my application scheduler stop and android debug console go empty.
Btw onPause and onStops method I start beepForAnHour() method.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); 
     };
     final ScheduledFuture beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` runs on same process id as your application, i.e it is bonded to live as long as your application lives. You should use different approach to keep your `ScheduledExecutorService` alive, like starting it from a `Service` or use other independent scheduled method like `AlaramManager`.

Comment: So I have to execute my scheduled method (I mean peace of code which a want to execute) in AlarmManager without ScheduledExecutorService ?